# Orderby asc and desc in inner object value of Jarray using lambda

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, c#-4.0

I want to implement order by on the inner object of my JArray,Below is my Jarray,

```
[  
   {  
      "element1":"asjdlasjdlasd",
      "element2":"asdasd",
      "element3":[  
         {  
            "num":"1",
            "status":1
         },
         {  
            "num":"2",
            "status":2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Order by on element1 works fine but How would i order by on "status" ?
Order by on element1 code ,
`jarray.OrderBy(x => (JValue)x["element1"])`

Comment: Include your c# order by code, please.

Comment: Updated to my question.

Comment: What do you want to do with elements that don't have a status?

Comment: Do you want the overall list of elements ordered by they're `status`? Or Do you want the sub-elements ordered by their status?

Comment: I want order by on element3 valuesm @dckuehn

Comment: `status` is compulsory @GiladGreen

Comment: Does cumpulsory imply required, because your first two elements do not have a status, and your last has two statuses.  It's not clear how expect these to sort.  Is your example valid and how you want it ordered?

Comment: Also, what package are these JArray objects from?

Comment: status always comes under the element3 itself! @dckuehn